# How to make function initMap() wait in between its execution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have two functions

```
function otherfun(val){
    var data = {'latitude': val[0], 'longitude': val[1]};
    $.post(URL, data, function(response){
        if(response){ 
           // I want to return response from here
        }
        else{ alert('Error! :('); }
    });
}


function initMap() {

      var pos = {};
      if (navigator.geolocation) {

      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };

        var output = otherfun([pos.lat,pos.lng]);

        alert(output);
        // use output's value further

}
```

Function initMap() executes initially. I am passing the value of lat and lng to otherfun()

I want to:

1. Return the value of response from function otherfun.
2. Make initMap() function to wait for the return of otherfun() and store in variable output
3. And then show the alert box with output value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split initMap in two functions. The original init and the callback function called after otherfun.

```
function otherfun(val) {
    var data = {'latitude': val[0], 'longitude': val[1]};
    $.post(URL, data, function(response){
        if(response){ 
           otherfunCallback(response);    // Call a callback function
        }
        else{ alert('Error! :('); }
    });
}

function initMap() {

      var pos = {};
      if (navigator.geolocation) {

      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };

        otherfun([pos.lat,pos.lng]);
}

// The callback function that alert for the output
function otherfunCallback(data) {
    // ... extract the data you need
    var output = ...;
    alert(output);   
}
```

If you need to store the output result you can save it in a variable not locale.